# Make the whole DataGrid row editable in SelectionChanged event

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a DataGrid which is bound to some data. I have implemented the SelectionChanged event. Now my problem is that I have to make the whole row editable on the selection changed. Any help???

Comment: You Should Try To set DataGrid Template's Rows ReadOnly = False When You Select That Row